Dragging many independent formulas at once in Google Sheets
I have a Sheet named Sheet1 like:



No.
1st Part
2nd Part
data1st
data2nd
title
desc
meta1
meta2
note




1
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j


2
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t



I want to generate another sheet based in this data, reordeing its data as:



-
-
-




b
c
f


merged with (b)
merged with (c)
h


merged with (b)
merged with (c)
i


merged with (b)
merged with (c)
j


d
e
merged with (j)


g
merged with (g)
merged with (j)



How would it be possible to set up these formulas so I can select all that rectangle, and drag it until the end of the sheet to generate the same rectangle for the second row in "Sheet1", etc.
Expected output:



-
-
-




b
c
f


merged with (b)
merged with (c)
h


merged with (b)
merged with (c)
i


merged with (b)
merged with (c)
j


d
e
merged with (j)


g
merged with (g)
merged with (j)


l
m
p


merged with (l)
merged with (m)
r


merged with (l)
merged with (m)
s


merged with (l)
merged with (m)
t


n
o
merged with (t)


q
merged with (q)
merged with (t)




It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Copy Cell Formats
Cells can't be merged using a function however you can set up the formatting in advance by creating the merged cells for one 6x3 block of cells, then pasting that formatting over subsequent blocks.

Setup the merge cell layout for the first 6 x 3 block of cells

Merge the necessary cells.
Set the horizontal and vertical alignment, fonts etc.


Select and Copy the block of cells.
Select the entire sheet by clicking on the tile in the top-left corner between the row 1 heading and the column A heading or CTRL+A
Paste using Paste special > Format only

Formula
The following formula will return the values for all blocks of cells. Place it in the top left cell of the first block.
=WRAPROWS(TOROW(BYROW(
    QUERY(Sheet1!B2:J, "WHERE B IS NOT NULL"), 
       LAMBDA(r, 
         MAP(HSTACK(1,2,5,,,7,,,8,,,9,3,4,,6,,),
           LAMBDA(i, IF(i, INDEX(r,,i),)))))),3)

BYROW  HSTACK  IF  INDEX  LAMBDA  MAP  QUERY  TOROW  WRAPROWS
Explanation

QUERY is used to remove empty rows from the range.
BYROW passes the results from QUERY, row-by-row into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row in r.
A 1x18 array is created using r's column index numbers in their final order in a flattened version of the 6x3 block of cells.
That array of indexes and empty values is mapped, value by value, into another LAMBDA function that stores the current index/value in i.
If i contains a number, the  LAMBDA's formula uses i as the column argument for INDEX to retrieve the correct column from r.
This is repeated for each i, and then repeated for the next r until all r have been processed. The result is an array that has as many rows as there were populated rows in the original range and 18 columns.
TOROW transforms that array into a single row, and then WRAPROWS transforms it into an array that is 3 columns WIDE matching the final layout.


This works well, but If cells cant be merged, how would it be to concatenate the rows f,h,i with a new line between them to make them all in one cell?

I'm not clear why you can't merge the cells, I've edited the answer to add more info about how to set the format across the sheet.
